# Deployment Diagram for Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, diagram

I have a simple Spring Boot application that uses local PostgresSQL database and I only run this application locally.

For it, I need to create a deployment diagram, but I do not quite understand what components should be present.

I managed to create the following diagram, but I suspect that it is very far from ideal:
[image]

Perhaps I also need to add some component related to Maven or JVM?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some remarks:

1. I am not sure if you really need a deployment diagram or a component diagram, or a mixture. That depends on the target audience.
2. The deployment diagram shows the physical deployment (where is the software executed?). The dependency arrows can be used, but keep in mind that a consumer and producer do not necessarily mean that a consumer depends on the producer (dependency injection and inversion of control).
   https://www.softwareideas.net/a/1580/e-commerce-microservices-uml-deployment-diagram-
3. The UML component diagram shows the functionality in terms of the implementation (structural aspects). Here, consumers and producers (APIs) can be modeled (usually with the lollipop notaton), e.g.
   https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242960303_Mobile_Agents_A_Key_for_Eectiv_e_Pervasive_Computing
4. A JVM is a component from the software development perspective but also an artifact (you need to install the Java runtime system on a device/VM).
5. Please check your dependency from the Tomcat server to the browser: Does the Web server really depends on a client PC? This is highly unlikely.